# Why does Webklex\IMAP\Client::getFolders() fail on Exchange Server?

Tags: php, laravel, imap

I use `Webklex\IMAP\Client::getFolders()` to get all folders of an IMAP mail account. It works fine on my Gmail and my GMX test account but fails on Exchange.

```
$oClient->connect(); //OK
$aAvailableFolders = $oClient->getFolders()->all(); //FAILS

Exception trace:
1   Webklex\IMAP\Client::getFolders("Kontakte/%")
  /var/www/html/jira42/vendor/webklex/laravel-imap/src/IMAP/Client.php:371
2   Webklex\IMAP\Client::getFolders()
  /var/www/html/jira42/app/Jobs/MailHandler.php:53
```

Comment: If it's still relevant, you don't need `->all()` to get your folders, `$client->Folders()` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

To get all available folders use

```
$aAvailableFolders = $oClient->getFolders();
```

Find a folder by path

```
$aAvailableFolders = $oClient->getFolderByPath('INBOX.name');
```

Find a folder by name

```
$aAvailableFolders = $oClient->getFolderByName('name');
```

Documentation https://www.php-imap.com/api/client